# add chosen plugin to dropdown list that is dynamically add within a dynamic gridview ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dynamic grid view with different controls that added dynamically to this grid ,and one of them is drop-down list control and the data source for this drop-down list is sql table ,
My request is: I need to add a chosen plugin to ddl control that is created dynamically whit in each grid view row created ,I can easily  deal with another gridview footer with below code:
$('#<%=gv_employee_Entity.FooterRow.Cells[6].FindControl("ddl_full_Crs_name").ClientID%>').chosen();
but I can't do that with a dynamic created data row

button and textbox to add gridview rows:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_no_of_records" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp
    <asp:Button ID="btn_add_rows" runat="server" Text="Add Rows" OnClick="btn_add_rows_Click" />
```

my grid view:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_employees" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="5">
    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SL NO.">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_emp_id" runat="server" Text="<%#Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="employee name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_emp_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Job Title">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_emp_job_title" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee Gender">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_emp_gender" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notes">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_note" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Directorate Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_direct_name" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" DataSourceID="lds_direct_name" DataTextField="Direct_name" DataValueField="Direct_name">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="select value"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:LinqDataSource runat="server" EntityTypeName="" ID="lds_direct_name" ContextTypeName="TrainingManagementSystem.Models.emp_trainingDataContext" Select="new (Direct_name)" TableName="tbl_Directorates"></asp:LinqDataSource>
                </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

code behind button click event to add rows:

```
    protected void btn_add_rows_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         AddRowsToGrid();
     }
    protected void AddRowsToGrid()
    {
        List<int> noofrows = new List<int>();
        int rows = 0;
        int.TryParse(txt_no_of_records.Text.Trim(), out rows);

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            noofrows.Add(i);
        }

        gv_employees.DataSource = noofrows;
        gv_employees.DataBind();

        if (gv_employees.Rows.Count > 0)
            Panel1.Visible = true;
        else
            Panel1.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community! Your question is a little unclear in my opinion. In order for you to get the best help from the community please consider cleaning up, simplifying and clarifying your question.